# How to redirect to Login view in MVC 4

Tags: routes, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I have created a new mvc 4 project using VS 2012.Now i run the application  it opens the Home/Index as it is set as default in RouteConfig.cs. I want to make the Account/Login as the first page for my project. I tried doing this by changing the default route to Account/Login but that doesn't work for me. Can anyone let me know is there anything else i need to take care other than this

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though your entire application requires the user to be authenticated, even your home controller.  You could add the AuthorizeAttribute to your HomeController and it should require that the user accessing it should be logged in first.

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I want to set the Account/login as my start page.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your default route is not the same as forcing a landing page on a user.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Changing the above to `controller="Account", action="Login"` will indeed handle any request coming in on any specified host header that you have configured on your site in IIS. However, it will not redirect any user with a legitimate route.

For this, you will indeed need to use the `[Authorize]` attribute that @mreyeros has mentioned. You can do this on each controller in your site, or you can create a new base controller that you can inherit from throughout the other controllers in your project.

If you really just want a redirect, you *could* take the same approach (new, attributed base controller to inherit from) and create your own RedirectOnLandingAttribute, but I think what you are trying to achieve is best approached by leveraging what the framework already has to offer.

Hope this helps.